# Check if object is within FOV (field of view) in Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, game-development

I am trying to create a game in Unity 3d where NPC's move and look around and check which objects are inside their view angle. To calculate what objects are inside the field of view angle i use unity's build in function Vector3.Angle, see:

```
// Get current position of the Robot.
var robotObjectPosition = currentTransform.parent.position;

// Get the direction to the object
var directionToObject = (objectToFind.transform.position - robotObjectPosition) / 2;

// Calculate the angle to the object and check if it's inside our viewAngle.
var isInsideAngle = Vector3.Angle(currentTransform.forward, directionToObject) < viewAngle / 2;
```

Now i have a weird problem where if i move to close to an object (a plane in the shape of a goal line in this case) the above check returns false, even though the object is still in front of it and the goal line is still clearly inside of his vision. I made a screenshot to visualize my problem.
In the first image the goal line is inside of his vision, but in the second ( i moved him a small step forward) the above function returns false, even though i can clearly see he is still in front of the object. I am geussing it has something to do with the width of the other object, (because i divide the viewangle by 2) but i havent been able to find a fix for it.

Mainly i would like to understand what is happening here.

[image: The goal line (white line) is still inside vision here]

[image: Here, i moved the robot a little bit further and suddenly the checks above now return false, and the line is no longer in his field of vision.]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code myself and got to the same result. The problem is you need to remember that the angle you are calculating has two important characteristics:
1. it checks for "objectToFind"'s center/pivot point. once the center is not inside the angle you will get false.
2. it is in 3D and not 2D so if you get closer the angle between the robot and the object (on the Y axis) does not include the center of the objectToFind.

As a solution I would cast a ray instead of checking if it is inside the angle range.
Hope that helps